# parallel quick sort outdone by single threaded quicksort

Tags: c++, concurrency, quicksort, future

I've been reading the book C++ concurrency in action, here is the example in the book using futures to implement parallel quick sort.

But I found this function is more than twice slower than the single threaded quick sort function without using any asynchronous facilities in c++ standard library.
Tested with g++ 4.8 and visual c++ 2012.

I used 10M random integers to test, and in visual c++ 2012,this function spawned 6 threads in total to perform the operation in my quad core PC.

I am really confused about the performance. Any body can tell me why?

```
template<typename T>
std::list<T> parallel_quick_sort(std::list<T> input)
{
    if(input.empty())
    {
        return input;
    }
    std::list<T> result;
    result.splice(result.begin(),input,input.begin());
    T const& pivot=*result.begin();
    auto divide_point=std::partition(input.begin(),input.end(),
        [&](T const& t){return t<pivot;});
    std::list<T> lower_part;
    lower_part.splice(lower_part.end(),input,input.begin(),
        divide_point);
    std::future<std::list<T> > new_lower(
        std::async(&parallel_quick_sort<T>,std::move(lower_part)));
    auto new_higher(
        parallel_quick_sort(std::move(input)));
    result.splice(result.end(),new_higher);
    result.splice(result.begin(),new_lower.get());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Show your single threaded version too - the sample code you have likely spends most extra time copying data to/from `result` instead of in place sorting...

Comment: i have followed the same book and  for me it work faster.  Also i got more insight by this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zE9N-KrsMBc&t=126s

Answer (score 1):

The code is just horribly sub-optimal. For example, why not `std::list<T> result(input)`? Why not `parallel_quick_sort(const std::list<T>& input`? Profile it and I bet you'll find all kinds of horrible things. Before you make any sense of code's performance, you have to make sure it's spending its time doing what you think it's doing!

Comment: I really doubt this (and test results provided). This is, basically, a parallel quicksort implementation from "C++ Concurency in action" by A.Williams (boost threads implementer). Using std::move, parallel algorithm runs significantly faster on large data. I very doubt the results of sequential quicksort for large data sizes either.